# How to include Yahoo stencils in Visio 2003?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Yahoo has published some stencils for use in Visio (http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/wireframes/)

How can I use these in Visio 2003?

Comment: Just open in Visio doesn't work?

Comment: D'oh!  I never even tried that - I was assuming that they were a collection of shapes I could add!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download the Visio Extension file: Visio(XML)
  from the Yahoo page
- Unzip the file

The zip contains *.vdx files. Unzip these and open directly in Visio. To do so, either:

- Double click directly on file in windows explorer

or

- In Visio: File > Open > Browse to File > Open